# Как в коде определить ширину элемента управления в Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

У меня есть два элемента управления: `TextView` и `LinearLayout`. Оба имеют ширину заданную в разметке интерфейса `wrap_content`. Затем в коде (`OnPostCreate`) я хочу изменить ширину `LinearLayout` и сделать её такой же как у `TextView`. Однако мне это не удаётся, потому что ширина `TextView` отображается как -2.

Как тут можно поступить?

Comment: А может распределение размеров после вашего кода идет? Попробуйте другие методы вроде onStart.

Comment: К сожалению, тоже не подходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данной ситуации нужно было переопределить метод View.onSizeChanged(...)
но я поступил проще (с моей точки зрения) - создал поток прослушивающий размеры нужных элементов и выдающий сообщение при их изменении

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте методы:
textView.getMeasuredWidth();
textView.getMeasuredHeight();

Либо задайте размеры виджета в dp.

Answer (score 1):

А почему не использовали **`addOnLayoutChangeListener`** ?
достаточно было добавить данный слушатель к TextView и потом просто при отработке данного события изменить размер слоя.

Думаю, для описанной цели, создавать отдельный поток - не самый изящный вариант...